# Insert an encoded character as text in a dynamically generated element using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to insert `&times;` into the text of a button that I'm generating dynamically via jquery:

```
var closebutton = $('<button/>',{
  "type": "button",
  "class": "close",
  "data-dismiss": "alert",
  "aria-hidden": true,
});
$(closebutton).text("&times;");
```

Because the `&times;` is wrapped in quotes it gets inserted as a string.

Is there a way to add this in as the encoded character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - use `html()` instead of `text()`.

```
closebutton.html("&times;");
```

Note that you don't need to re-wrap `closebutton` in `$()`, since it's already a jQuery object.